# SSH open to a different process than bash

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I have requirement at work that when ssh'ing into the device, instead of the usual process the user sees/runs at startup (bash), I need it to run a custom process -- one of my own, though it could theoretically be anything terminal-based.

How might I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution ended up not using chsh because it will not be installed on the system. I edited /etc/profile and changed /bin/sh for my user to my program. I assume that chsh just automated this, but either way this is the best solution given my requirements and limitations.

Answer (score 2):

You mean [changing the shell](https://serverfault.com/questions/106722/choosing-the-shell-that-ssh-uses)? Use [chsh](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chsh).

```
chsh -s /bin/ksh foo
chsh -s /bin/bash username
```

Comment: OK. Hadn't heard of chsh -- thank you for that. I guess it comes with using the right terms in a search. I assume I could stick this in a startup script (the user currently logs into ash, not bash), or do what one of the answers in that link said about "exec"?

Comment: Yeah, as the user mentions, adding that line to your bash login script should also work just fine.

Comment: I know. I was just wondering if maybe I should close/delete this question? It's almost exactly the same as the one you referenced.

Comment: No, at least the way I'm attempting to do it, it won't work. Let's say that I want to run a random python script on ssh open. Chsh probably won't work (and I'm not sure that I will have the luxury of editing the chsh list), but "exec" only provides errors on the script run.

Comment: Or I should say, for instance if I'm looking for any sort of user input on the keyboard, then nothing occurs until i give it, and then my print statements come about. Certainly, though, the script will run, which I guess is fortunate, and on completion it does kick me out of the session. So, perhaps this is the correct answer, even if it requires tweaks.